# how to print all first parameter json

Tags: php, json

how to get all data
i have some problem when i want to print my link in database and the format data in database is saved from `json_encode()` the data is `([{"link":"google.com"},{"link":"facebook.com"},{"link":"instagram.com"}])`, and i want to print as google.com, facebook.com, instagram.com in my web, i use codeigniter framework
i have tried this

```
$link = json_decode($row['LINK'], true);
$link[0]["link"];
```

and the result just google.com

Comment: $link[1] error, because the object just one and all data saved in object $link[0]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this way to get the domain link,

```
<?php
$row = '[{"link":"google.com"},{"link":"facebook.com"},{"link":"instagram.com"}]';
$array = json_decode($row,true);
foreach($array as $key=>$value){
    echo $value['link'].PHP_EOL;
}
?>
```

**DEMO:** https://3v4l.org/dElvA

OR `array_colunn()` to get all the domains in an array,

```
print_r(array_column($array,'link'));
```